# Reference Request- Black Hole Perturbation Theory (Teukolsky formulation)

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

I am involved in a project where I need to calculate a metric resulting from a perturbation.

In particular, I am doing perturbation on a Kerr Geometry. I am new to black hole perturbation theory. I know that this kind of perturbation on Kerr metric is usually done in Teukolsky formulation, which involves substantial use of Newman-Penrose Formalism, which I am not familiar of (too many symbols in NP formalism!)

I wonder whether anyone can introduce me a self-contained and concise review/note on Black Hole Perturbation Theory, on Teukolsky formulation, and most importantly on NP formalism and how it is actually used in black hole perturbation theory.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best reference, but there is a chapter about this in Maggiore Vol 2. Generally Maggiore is a really good starting point for topics on gravitational waves, he covered a lot of material.

Answer (score 1):

A classic: Chrandrasekhar, "The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes"

The first chapter contains a self-contained introduction to the NP formalism.

Chapter 9 discusses (among other things) the derivation of the Teukolsky equation.